# Laravel 5.1 - How to pass a variable from event::updating to event::updated?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to create a logging trait that would also save all changes to relationships (many to many).

So far my idea is to store the model with all the relationships in static::updating event of the loggable model as $original. And then fetch the $original variable in static::updated event and compare the differences and log accordingly.

What would be a good way to go about doing this. If there's a better method to doing this I'm happy to hear about it.

Comment: I would put extra attributes that I need to class in `updating` event and then access them in `updated` event. By saying attributes I mean something like `$model->extraInfo = ['a'=>'b', 'c'=>'d'];`

Comment: I just tried this. I put `$user->test = 'some data'` in ::updating and I get sql error  General error: 1 no such column: test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should define a `public/protected` variable and assign value to that variable in `updating` method, and access it in `updated` method.

eg:

```
public var $storeTemp = null;

public function boot()
{
    User::updating(function ($user) {
         $this->storeTemp = $user->testVal; //or assign object
    });

    User::updated(function ($user) {
       print_r($this->storeTemp);//print or access value
    });

}
```